# C++ class template parameter must have a specific parent class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, derived-class

Given is a class `MyClass` with one template parameter

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    //...
};
```

and another class `MySecondClass` with two template parameters.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class MySecondClass
{
    //...
};
```

What I would like to do is to restrict `MyClass` to only allow a `T` that is a derived type of `MySecondClass`.  I already know I need something like

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<MySecondClass<?,?>, T>::value>>
class MyClass
{
    //...
}
```

I am just not sure what to put in for the `?` as I want to allow all possible `MySecondClass`'s.

Comment: I edited the question.  If you feel that it is not correct please roll it back

Comment: I wonder about the point of the exercise. How do you plan to use the fact that `T` is derived from some instantiation of `MyParentClass`? What do you believe you can do with `T` knowing this, that you couldn't do otherwise?

Comment: why do you keep changing the question?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I want to search for an object of a subclass `X` of `MySecondClass` in a Vector and store a reference to this object in the instantiation of `MyClass<X>` which can be then accessed with a getter `X getMySecondClassChild()` in `MyClass<X>`.

Comment: No part of your explanation appears to require that `X` be derived from `MySecondClass`. The only connection thereto is the name of the method, `getMySecondClassChild`. Call it `getX` instead, and `MySecondClass` is completely out of the picture.

Comment: MySecondClass is a abstract class (with several pure virtual functions). All subclasses X of MySecondClass should implement these pure virtual functions and inherit already implemented functions. Im MyClass I want to enforce that the getter always returns a X. Perhaps I should create a new question for this design problems...

Answer (score 7):

You can use a template template parameter for the base template, then check if a `T*` can be converted to some `Temp<Args...>`:

```
template <template <typename...> class Of, typename T>
struct is_base_instantiation_of {
    template <typename... Args>
    static std::true_type test (Of<Args...>*);
    static std::false_type test (...);

    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<T*>()));
    static constexpr auto value = type::value;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a90f49ac40bc09ac)

Comment: Your live demo fails to compile...

Comment: @Cornstalks I believe that is the point as `int` don't derive from `MyParentClass` template class (hence `enable_if_t` fails and makes sure `MyClass` is not part of the overload resolution for `MyClass<int>`).

Comment: @dfri: Ah, you're right. I misread it. A comment on the two lines indicating that "compilation will fail here" would have helped make it clear the failure is intentional.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom trait to check whether a type is derived from a template. Then use this trait inside a `static_assert`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename...> class T, typename U>
struct is_derived_from_template
{
private:
    template <typename... Args>
    static decltype(static_cast<const T<Args...>&>(std::declval<U>()), std::true_type{}) test(
            const T<Args...>&);
    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<U>()))::value;
};


template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct MyParentClass
{
};

template<typename T>
struct MyClass
{
    static_assert(is_derived_from_template<MyParentClass, T>::value, "T must derive from MyParentClass");
};


struct DerivedFromMyParentClass : MyParentClass<int, float>{};

struct Foo{};

int main()
{
    MyClass<DerivedFromMyParentClass> m;
    MyClass<Foo> f;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fc40f1abd212cf1)